# How to load or open DICOM image file in java without using ImageJ library?

Tags: java, netbeans, platform, dicom

i m make App in netbeans platform in java swing. first i want to load or open DICOM image file  without using ImageJ library in java.so how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a dedicated open-source DICOM library for loading DICOM images I would recommend PixelMed Java DICOM Toolkit, available [here](http://www.dclunie.com/pixelmed/software/).

Comment: i checked it, but can't understand that how can use it?

Comment: If you primarily intend to display the image, you should be able to use [SourceImage](http://www.dclunie.com/pixelmed/software/javadoc/com/pixelmed/display/SourceImage.html) and [SingleImagePanel](http://www.dclunie.com/pixelmed/software/javadoc/com/pixelmed/display/SingleImagePanel.html) from the _com.pixelmed.display_ package to load and display the image. If you want to parse DICOM attributes, you could start with one of the _read_ methods in [com.pixelmed.dicom.AttributeList](http://www.dclunie.com/pixelmed/software/javadoc/com/pixelmed/dicom/AttributeList.html).